# How to add '.aar' file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, aar

I have some `.aar` files. I added them in Project by right clicking on project, then add new Module, there i selected `Import .jar .aar Package`.

This added the `.aar` file in my project, along with a newly created `.gradle` file.

**New Gradle File**

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('SDKTest-rel-1.01.aar'))
```

Now when i try to add this file in my `build.gradle` file, it gives me error messages

> Failed to resolve: SDKTest-rel-1.01.

and i am unable to use classes of this `SDK` in my program.

Kindly guide me and tell me some other way of adding and using `.aar` files.

Answer (score 7):

In a recent update the people at android broke the inclusion of local aar files via the Android Studio's add new module menu option. Check the [Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55863) listed here. Following method works for local .aar files
Put the aar file in the libs directory (create it if needed), then, add the following code in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   compile(name:'nameOfYourAARFileWithoutExtension', ext:'aar')
 }
repositories{
      flatDir{
              dirs 'libs'
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

To add .aar file as dependency, you need to create folder in the application module, copy the .aar file to it, and add the file as repository.

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
      dirs 'aars'
        }
   }
```

This will make it possible to add any file inside the folder as dependency. You can reference the dependency as follow:

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'libraryname', ext:'aar')
   }
```

This tell the Gradle to look for a library with a certain name that has the **.aar** extension.